# Open new window on ActionColumn click Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How can I open a new Window when I click either of the 'view', 'delete', 'update' button in Yii2 framework?

below is the ActionColumn Image.

[image: CLick Here]

Comment: Have you use ajax gridview ?

Answer (score 4):

You can do that by just overriding the `button` property of `yii\grid\ActionColumn` and setting attribute `target='_blank'` into link.

e.g,

```
                        [
                            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                            'buttons' => [
                                'view' => function ($url, $model) {
                                    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" title="View Details"></span>', $url, ['data-pjax' => 0, 'target' => "_blank"]);
                                },
                                        'update' => function ($url, $model) {

                                    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Update"></span>',$url, ['data-pjax' => 0, 'target' => "_blank"]);
                                },
                                        'delete' => function ($url, $model) {
                                    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" title= "Delete"></span>', $url, ['data-pjax' => 0, 'target' => "_blank"]);
                                },
                                    ],
                                ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the buttonOptions property to the ActionColumn like:

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 
    'buttonOptions' => [
        'target' => "_blank"
     ]
]
```